How to change port of Geoserver to connect with Geonode/Cartoview on port 8081 instead of 8080(default)?
i would like to know how to change Geoserver port to connect with Geonode/Cartoview? Geonode/Cartoview comes with Geoserver already. And Geonode connects from port 8000 to Geoserver on port 8080. I want to change port to 8081 so that i can run multiples instances of Geonode/Cartoview and Geoserver on the same VM. Thanks in advance.

how did you install geoserver? which Servlet Engine are you using? Have you read the manual for that engine to see how ports are allocated to servlets?

Geonode/Cartoview comes preconfigured with Geoserver @IanTurton , i have read documentation and no where i found where to change ports. i just ran paver setup_geoserver and paver start_geoserver and it ran Geoserver

it probably uses jetty servlet engine

unless you know where GeoServer is running and how it is configured then we can't really help you.
